# Serial Port not working but work in hyper terminal

Tags: c#, serial-port, hyper-v

I implement application Serial Port with C# and send data using it.
but don't working. 
I send "A" character and my hardware not working
but I send it by hyper terminal Application or SimpleTerm and worked.

my Code application :

```
if (_port.IsOpen)
            {
                _port.Close();
            }
            _port.PortName = cmport.Text;
            _port.Parity = (Parity)Enum.Parse(typeof(Parity), cmparity.Text);
            _port.StopBits = (StopBits)Enum.Parse(typeof(StopBits), cmstopbit.Text);
            _port.DataBits = Convert.ToInt32(cmdatabit.Text);
            _port.BaudRate = Convert.ToInt32(cmboundrate.Text);
            _port.Handshake = Handshake.None;
            if (!_port.IsOpen)
                    {
                        _port.Open();
                    }

                    _port.Write(textBoxX1.Text.Trim());
```

Comment: Use Handshake.RequestToSend, delete all _port.Close() calls from your code.

Answer (score 2):

when you are using hyper terminal it will add a Carriage return.
you have to add \r after your text.
Example :A\r

Answer (score 1):

How is your serial port configured?

Check this website : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/SerialPort-brief-Example-ac0d5004

```
using System; 
using System.IO.Ports; 
using System.Text; 

namespace SerialPortExample 
{ 
    /// <summary> 
    /// Interfaces with a serial port. There should only be one instance 
    /// of this class for each serial port to be used. 
    /// </summary> 
    public class SerialPortInterface 
    { 
        private SerialPort _serialPort = new SerialPort(); 
        private int _baudRate = 9600; 
        private int _dataBits = 8; 
        private Handshake _handshake = Handshake.None; 
        private Parity _parity = Parity.None; 
        private string _portName = "COM1"; 
        private StopBits _stopBits = StopBits.One; 


    /// <summary> 
    /// Holds data received until we get a terminator. 
    /// </summary> 
    private string tString = string.Empty; 
    /// <summary> 
    /// End of transmition byte in this case EOT (ASCII 4). 
    /// </summary> 
    private byte _terminator = 0x4; 

    public int BaudRate { get { return _baudRate; } set { _baudRate = value; } } 
    public int DataBits { get { return _dataBits; } set { _dataBits = value; } } 
    public Handshake Handshake { get { return _handshake; } set { _handshake = value; } } 
    public Parity Parity { get { return _parity; } set { _parity = value; } } 
    public string PortName { get { return _portName; } set { _portName = value; } } 
    public bool Open() 
    { 
        try 
        { 
            _serialPort.BaudRate = _baudRate; 
            _serialPort.DataBits = _dataBits; 
            _serialPort.Handshake = _handshake; 
            _serialPort.Parity = _parity; 
            _serialPort.PortName = _portName; 
            _serialPort.StopBits = _stopBits; 
            _serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(_serialPort_DataReceived); 
        } 
        catch { return false; } 
        return true; 
    } 

    void _serialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e) 
    { 
        //Initialize a buffer to hold the received data 
        byte[] buffer = new byte[_serialPort.ReadBufferSize]; 

        //There is no accurate method for checking how many bytes are read 
        //unless you check the return from the Read method 
        int bytesRead = _serialPort.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length); 

        //For the example assume the data we are received is ASCII data. 
        tString += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead); 
        //Check if string contains the terminator  
        if (tString.IndexOf((char)_terminator) > -1) 
        { 
            //If tString does contain terminator we cannot assume that it is the last character received 
            string workingString = tString.Substring(0, tString.IndexOf((char)_terminator)); 
            //Remove the data up to the terminator from tString 
            tString = tString.Substring(tString.IndexOf((char)_terminator)); 
            //Do something with workingString 
            Console.WriteLine(workingString); 
        } 
    } 

} 
}
```

***Does your textBoxX1.Text.Trim() contains the end char? (_terminator) :)***

***EDIT:*** Entire project to send data to the com serveur.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/678025/Serial-Comms-in-Csharp-for-Beginners

I really think that you should add \r\n to the text you are sending to the COM, this will tell to the port com that the line is complete and will read it.

Try this:

```
_port.Write(textBoxX1.Text.Trim() + "\r\n");
```

Comment: when use _port.Write(textBoxX1.Text.Trim() + "\r\n"); print a empty character on lcd device.

Comment: I think this is because \n or \r is not mendatory to close the client buffer.
Try only \r or \n.
Does it work? (even with an empty char)

Comment: i try to use it but not working. when port USB 2.0 can send 12 character but when use USB 3.0 not send above 5 character